# Oracle Sort inline view by variable name not working in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, plsql

Thank you very much in advance for looking at my issue.

Summary: 
I want to sort inline view by variable name, &pSortColumn.
In Query (see below), it works nicely. However, in PL SQL, no sorting is done!!!

Query below SORTED correctly

```
SELECT  RUV2.*
FROM

    (SELECT ROWNUM AS ROW_ID, RUV1.*
     FROM

        (SELECT         
                    ru.ENTERPRISE_ID,
                    ru.LEGAL_NAME
        FROM    
        TB_REPORTING_UNIT ru
        WHERE       ru.REFYEAR = 2012   

        ORDER BY    &pSortColumn     
        ) RUV1
    ) RUV2 ;
```

PL SQL below NOT SORTING at all

```
OPEN    cur_ReportingUnit FOR

   SELECT  RUV2.*
   FROM
        (SELECT ROWNUM AS ROW_ID, RUV1.*
         FROM
             (SELECT         
                     ru.ENTERPRISE_ID,
                     ru.LEGAL_NAME 
              FROM    
                     TB_REPORTING_UNIT ru
              WHERE  ru.REFYEAR = 2012  
              ORDER BY pSortColumn    
            ) RUV1

        ) RUV2 ;

      LOOP
          FETCH cur_ReportingUnit INTO mRow_Id, mEnterprise_ID, mLegal_Name ;     
            EXIT WHEN (cur_ReportingUnit%notfound) ;

          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (mEnterprise_ID || ' --- ' || mLegal_Name ) ;
      END LOOP;
```

Comment: My PL SQL as below - NOT SORTING at all

Answer (score 1):

Add the sorting clause to the most outer query

Comment: I am implementing Oracle paging. Therefore, the ORDER BY clause must be in the innermost SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

For paging with a "window", you can do something like this:

```
select e.*
from   ( select e.*
         ,      row_number() 
                over 
                (order by uur_id) ive$idx$ 
         from   bubs_uren_v e 
         where ( uur_id = :w1 )
       ) e 
where  ive$idx$ between (:start_index + 1) and (:start_index + :max_row_count)
```

We use this code in our project management suite which handles very large volumes of data. Don't ask me how Oracle did it, but it consistently fast. Remember to only include the columns you need, saves processing, memory and maybe even PL/SQL function calls.